# .net DLL error while trying to run application

Tags: asp.net, dll, oledb

I am getting the below error message while trying to run my application.

"The Microsoft Ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine."

Please help me solve this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Ace.oledb.12.0 might be 32-bit dll. you should enable 32-bit applications to run on IIS application pool your site is running since

1. Right click on the Application Pool and select “Advanced Settings…” 
   or select the same from the Actions pane after selecting the
   Application pool
2. Change the “Enable 32-bit Applications” to True
3. Click OK